# get value from <option> with javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how can I get the value from all the `<option>` with javascript?

example:

```
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

How can I using javascript to retrieved all the value from `<option>` and output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pie:

```
var opts = document.getElementById('test').options;
var vals = [];
for(var i = 0, j = opts.length; i < j; i++) 
   vals.push(opts[i].value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` instead of explicitly looping.

```
var options = document.getElementById('test').options;

var values = Array.prototype.map.call(options, function(val) {
    return val.value;
});
```

Though you'll need to add it to `Array.prototype` if you're supporting older browsers.

There's an implementation at MDC you can use:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

---

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thus affirming how out of touch I am with JavaScript. Awesome answer.

Comment: @Phil: Thanks. :o) It'll be nice when all the cool new features have wide support.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = document.getElementById('test').options;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionsCollection

**Edit:** For completeness

```
var options = document.getElementById('test').options;
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options.item(i);
    var value = option.value || option.text; // For IE
    values.push(value);
}
```

From memory, some versions of Internet Explorer do not return the option's text content for the `value` property if no `value` attribute is set.

Comment: That doesn't give you values...

Comment: @eyelidlessness I'm more of a "teach a man to fish" type guy ;)

Comment: that's fine, I guess, except I don't think it's necessarily the spirit of the site. Regardless, it's probably best to explain that that's what you're doing when you post an answer that doesn't actually solve the question.

Comment: @eyelidlessness You're right, SO is a site for *answers*. That's why I edited mine

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with JavaScript like this

```
var opt = document.getElementById('idOfYourSelect').options;

for (var i = 0, ii = opt.length; i < ii; i++) {
    console.log(opt[i].value);
}
```

if you using jQuery it can be like this

```
var opt = $('#idOfYourSelect options');

for (var i = 0, ii = opt.length; i < ii; i++) {
    console.log(opt[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recomment use for this an jQuery library & use .each() method for query an all "options" tags under defined "select".

Answer (score 0):

I wanted all values and its labels so i used below code

```
var opts = document.getElementById('state_of_birth').options;
var vals = [];
var txt = [];
for(i=0,j=opts.length;i<j;i++) 
{
    vals.push(opts[i].value);
    txt.push(opts[i].text);
}
var k=i;
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    window.alert(vals[i]);
    window.alert(txt[i]);
}
```